# How to autologin with XDM?

Tags: configuration, options, display-manager, autologin

How to autologin a specified user with `xdm`?

I know it's possible with other display managers but I wasn't able to figure out how `xdm` has to be configured to autologin a certain user.

Is it possible? Or should I rather remove `xdm` and simply use an initscript with `startx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used `xdm` in a long while but as far as I know *autologin* is not supported by `xdm` (and, as per one of the devs, [not needed](http://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2003/07/msg00267.html)).